# ExtJs json response custom transformation to store model

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I use ExtJs 4.1.3 and have the following scenario: 
1. ExtJs grid which use some store with model

```
//model  
Ext.define('MyApp.model.Tariff', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        {
            name: 'country',
            type: 'string'
        },
        {
            name: 'tariff',
            type: 'string'
        }
    ]
});

//grid   
var tariffsGrid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    id: 'tariffsGridId',
    title: 'Tariffs',
    store: tariffsStore,
    columns: [
        { text: 'Country', dataIndex: 'country' },
        { text: 'Tariff', dataIndex: 'tariff' }              
    ]
});
```

2. Http api which returns json

```
{
  countries: [...],
  tariffs: [..]
}
```

I want to get this json with ajax request and transform it according to some logic to the array of model MyApp.model.Tariff.

**How I can correctly implement this ?**

I have two ideas:

1. Make custom reader (extend: 'Ext.data.reader.Json') and use it for proxy in store
2. Override load method of the store and use Ext.Ajax.request

**Which design is better and please post example of the implementation**.

Comment: The same ideas have come to me. I would prefer overwrite `getResponseData` method in new class which extends `'Ext.data.reader.Json`. Do you have any troubles using this solution?

Comment: @afschr, do you have a working code example of this solution ?